# new line doesn't work in return statement in python

Tags: python

how do i fix this? is there something wrong with my code? new line is not working

```
def check_winner(a,b):
    if a==b:
        return f"Draw \n Both are {player1}"
    elif (a==1 and b==2) or (a==2 and b==1):
        if a==2:
            return f"Paper beats Rock \n player1 was:{player1} \n comp1 was:{comp1} \n Player1 Wins"
        else:
            return f"Paper beats Rock \n player1 was:{player1} \n comp1 was:{comp1} \n Computer Wins"
    elif (a==1 and b ==3) or (a==3 and b==1):
        if a==1:
            return f"Rock beats Scissor \n player1 was:{player1} \n comp1 was:{comp1} \n Player1 Wins"
        else:
            return f"Rock beats Scissor \n player1 was:{player1} \n comp1 was:{comp1} \n Computer Wins"
    elif (a==2 and b ==3) or (a==3 and b==2):
        if a==3:
            return f"Scissor beats paper \n player1 was:{player1} \n comp1 was:{comp1} \n Player1 Wins"
        else:
            return f"Scissor beats paper \n player1 was:{player1} \n comp1 was:{comp1} \n Computer Wins"
    else:
        pass
```

**Output:** `check_winner(1,3)`

```
'Rock beats Scissor \n player1 was:rock \n comp1 was:scissor \n Player1 Wins'
```

Comment: That's the `repr` of the string, not the string itself. If you `print` the strings, the ``\n`` will be rendered as newlines.

Answer (score 0):

you just have to understand what `return` actually does. `return` does not process the object or any variable it has, it just gives out to the global scope from the local/ functional scope.
On the other hand to work any **escape charater** such as `\n` has to process the string.
that's why `\n` works in your case.
so, to process this you can use `print()`, `logger.info()` or some string processing function outside the function scope. Or just `print()` before `return`